# How do you simplify in writing $[1, \infty) \cap [2, \infty) \cap [3, \infty) \ldots $ , in Real Analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

I know the answer to this very basic question in plain language but I want to know the right way to say it in real analysis:

$$\begin{align}
\text{If} \ A_t &= \{x \mid t \leq x\}, \\
\bigcap_{t \in \mathbb N}A_t &= [1, \infty) \cap [2, \infty) \cap [3, \infty) \ldots \\
&= \ldots
\end{align}$$

Which one should be the correct answer here?
(1) $[n, \infty)$, where $n = \max \ \mathbb N$ 
(2) $[n, \infty)$, where $n = \sup \ \mathbb N$ 
(3) $(\infty, \infty)$.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, none of those options are correct,  since $\Bbb N$ is unbounded neither $\max\Bbb N$ nor $\sup\Bbb N$ exist.  In fact,

$$\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}[n,\infty)=\emptyset.$$

The notation $(\infty,\infty)$ can be considered correct I suppose, but $(\infty,\infty)=\emptyset$.

Comment: $\sup \mathbf{N} = \infty$

Comment: @Hurkyl: That would depend on your convention. For example, if you take the definition given in the second paragraph [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum), the supremum wouldn't exist.

Comment: @Michael: $\infty$ *is* the least extended real number that is greater than or equal to every element of $\mathbf{N}$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: That is true, but if we were working in the extended real number system we would have $\infty \in A_t$ for every $t$. As the OP wrote $A_1 = [1, \infty)$ rather than $[1, \infty]$, I believe that we are working within $\mathbb{R}$ where the linked definition would say the supremum doesn't exist.

Comment: @Tim Raczkowski : Thanks! So if the question is asking $\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb R^+} = [t_1, \infty) \cup [t_2, \infty) \ldots$, then the answer would also be $\emptyset$ since $ t_n = min \  \mathbb R^+ = \emptyset$? Thanks again!

Comment: @A.Magnus Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski : In general context, which one is correct to say:  max $\mathbb N = \emptyset$ or sup $\mathbb N = \emptyset$? Thanks again!

Comment: Well you can't say either one. $\max\Bbb N$ and $\sup\Bbb N$ are numbers, whereas $\emptyset$ is a set.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski : Can I just say DNE, Does Not Exist?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: Prefer `.$$` to `$$.`. Prefer `\max E` to `\max\{E\}`, to denote the maximum of some set `E`, ditto for the supremum.

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is $\emptyset$. (1) is actually wrong, since $\max{\mathbb{N}}$ doesn't exist. The other two are technically correct but suggest a lack of understanding of $\infty$ (it's not a number and you can't treat it like one!)

Comment: @user73985 : Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, $\{\mathbb{N}\}$ is a set with one element, and that element is a set; in particular, $\{\mathbb{N}\} \not\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, so $\max\{\mathbb{N}\}$ and $\sup\{\mathbb{N}\}$ don't make sense. I believe you mean $\operatorname{max}\mathbb{N}$ and $\sup\mathbb{N}$.

As $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above, both $\operatorname{max}\mathbb{N}$ and $\sup\mathbb{N}$ don't exist, so $(1)$ and $(2)$ are incorrect. As for $(3)$, I don't know what $(\infty, \infty)$ is supposed to mean; usually such an interval isn't defined. Intuitively, it should be the set with no elements, i.e. the empty set $\emptyset$. The empty set is the correct answer because if $y \in \bigcap_{t \in \mathbb{N}}A_t$, then $y \in A_t$ for every $t \in \mathbb{N}$, so $y \geq t$ for every $t \in \mathbb{N}$, but no such element exists.

Comment: You are right, I mean max $\mathbb N$ and sup $\mathbb N$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The sets $A_t$ in this question are tacitly supposed to be sets of real numbers. Since by the Archimedian principle for every real number $x$ there is a natural number $n>x$  the intersection $\bigcap_{\>t\in{\mathbb N}} A_t$ is **empty**. Everything else is bullshit and trying to make a measly sense out of a poorly composed exercise.