# Infinity and the Maximum of Natural Number

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am posting this question in the wake of my similar posting [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1105657/how-do-you-simplify-in-writing-1-infty-cap-2-infty-cap-3-infty-l). What I have concluded there is that infinity $\infty$ stands for something without limit, the $\max  (\mathbb N)$ and $\min (\mathbb N)$ do not exist, so do that of the $\mathbb R$. Having said that, let's take a look at this problem down here:

$$\begin{align}
A_t &= \{x \mid t^2 \leq x \leq (t+1)^2 \} \tag{1} \\
\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb N} A_t &= [1, 4] \cup [4, 9] \cup [9, 16]\cup [16, 25] \ldots \tag{2}\\
&= \tag{3}\ldots
\end{align}$$

My first reaction is to take $[1, \infty)$ as the answer since the right element moves to the right without limit. However, in the spirit of yesterday's posting, which do you think is the correct answer and what is your explanation:

(a) $[1, \infty)$, or 
(b) $\emptyset$, since $\max (\mathbb N)$ does not exist?

And here is another beginner question:

$$\begin{align}
A_t &= \{x \mid -t \leq x \leq t \} \tag{4} \\
\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb N} A_t &= [-1, 1] \cup [-2, 2] \cup [-3, 3] \ldots \tag{5}\\
&= \tag{6}\ldots
\end{align}$$

Again, which do you think is the correct answer and what is your explanation:

(c) $(-\infty, \infty)$, or 
(d) $\emptyset$, since $\max (\mathbb N)$ does not exist?

Thank you for your time and effort.

**POST SCRIPT: ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~** 
Questions edited per request from moderators. Note also that this question is on the first chapter of Measure & Integration, so the concept of Extended Real Number is not there yet.

Comment: $\min(\mathbb{N})$ certainly does exist, even if mathematicians can't seem to agree on whether it should be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In yesterday's post you were taking an intersection,

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \,[n,\infty).$$

The answer to this is $\emptyset$ because there is no number which belongs to every $[n,\infty)$.

Today you are looking at a union,

$$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \,[n^2, (n+1)^2].$$

This is the collection of numbers which are in any of the intervals $[n^2, (n+1)^2]$. 
So your original guess $[1,\infty]$ in the extended real numbers is correct.

Edit: As J. Moravitz points out $\infty$ is not in any of the intervals. So $[1,\infty)$ is correct even in the extended real numbers.

Comment: yes this i think this corrects the OP

Comment: That is in the *extended real numbers* though, should mention that if not working in extended real numbers, but in the normal real numbers, answer should read $[1,\infty)$ (which despite the parenthesis is still a closed set since its complement, $(-\infty,1)$, is open).

Comment: @JMoravitz Quite right.  I did mention that the answer was correct in the extended real number system, but comparing it to usual system of reals is a good point.

Comment: @JMoravitz  If working in the extended real numbers the answer *still* should read $[1,\infty)$ because the point $\infty$ does not belong to any of the intervals $[n^2,(n+1)^2]$.

Comment: Oh right! I missed that.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski : Nice to meet you again! This problem comes from the first homework on Measure & Integration, which is the beginner's analysis so the Extended Real Number is not there yet. Do you think your answer to $[1, \infty)$ still holds if we are in the realm of Real Number only? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes. In the real numbers, $\infty$ is never included.

Comment: Sorry I think I did not phrase my question correctly: Do you think this $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \,[n^2, (n+1)^2] = [1, \infty)$ is still correct if it is NOT in Extended Real Number? Thanks.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm saying.

Comment: @TimRaczkowski : Always thanks!

Comment: @Magnus: It's interesting you would say that: when I learned the subject formally, extended real numbers were explicitly taught *before* measures and Lebesgue integration, as it makes it much easier to talk about such things.

Answer (score 4):

First, $\Bbb{N}$ is the set of positive integers, so it is bounded below by zero. This means $\min{\Bbb{N}}=0$ or $1$, depending on whether or not you allow $0$ in the natural numbers. Your intuition on your first question is almost right, but you should find $$\bigcup_{t \in \Bbb{N}} \{x \mid t^2 \leq x \leq (t+1)^2 \} = [1,\infty)$$ because $\infty \notin \Bbb{R}$ as $\infty$ is not a number, and does not belong in the set $\Bbb{R}$ of all real numbers. The half open interval $[1,\infty)$ makes that clear. On your second problem, the answer should be $(-\infty, \infty)$ for similar reasons. For all $y\in \Bbb{R}$ you can find $t \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $|y| \leq t$, and hence $y \in [-t,t]$, which means $$\Bbb{R} \subseteq \bigcup_{t \in \Bbb{N}} \{x \mid -t \leq x \leq t \}$$ The reverse inclusion follows easily since a union of subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ is itself a subset of $\Bbb{R}$, so you have $$\bigcup_{t \in \Bbb{N}} \{x \mid -t \leq x \leq t \} = \Bbb{R} = (-\infty, \infty)$$

Comment: The reason $\infty$ is not in the union is not because $\infty\notin\mathbb R$ or because $\infty$ is not a number; it's simply because $\infty$ is not in any of the intervals that make up the union.

Comment: @bof That is true. But at the same time, isn't $\infty$ not in any of the intervals that make up the union because each interval is an interval of real numbers, and hence won't contain infinity?

Comment: @graydad : Thanks! I stand to be corrected on $min \ \mathbb N$ = 0 or 1, as well as on $[1, \infty]$. Thanks again.

Comment: @A.Magnus happy to help and hope I could clear up everything.

Answer (score -2):

No.

$$
\bigcup_{t\in\mathbb N} A_t
$$
is just shorthand for
$$
\lim_{M\to\infty}\bigcup_{t=1}^{M} A_t
$$

So it doesn't matter that $\max\mathbb N$ doesn't exist.

Comment: No, $\bigcup_{t \in \mathbb{N}} A_t$ is shorthand for $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \in A_t \text{ for some } t \in \mathbb{N}\}$. The latter expression you wrote doesn't make sense — what is a limit of sets supposed to mean? (One could consider subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ as a poset ordered by inclusion, in which case unions are examples of direct limits (i.e., colimits), but categorical (co)limits are conceptually a lot more advanced than topological limits, so it wouldn't be very appropriate in this context anyway, and certainly would require clarification.)